# Dynamic FileFormat conversion - C Programming

Tags: c, file-io

I'm a beginner in "C" programming.
I'm planning to convert the input file into a different format / output file using some kind of static configuration file.

For e.g:
Input File content:
HDRUS15Jan2014153600MY22Jan2014000000KUL
DTLUSANZABC Private Company, Arizona 53213.
DTLMYKULJS Sdn Bhd, Kuala Lumpur 49000 .

Output File content:
ANZ15Jan2014153600
ABC Private Company, Arizona 53213.
KUL22Jan2014000000
JS Sdn Bhd, Kuala Lumpur 49000 .

Hints:
The input file format is fixed length and HDR & DTL keywords are the line identifiers.
I wanted to avoid implementing the hardcoding of extracting the content, instead i wanted to have a kind of configuration file...based on the configuration file the input file content will be extracted and construct the output files.

This concept will allow me to produce additional information in the output file in future without modifying the source code.
I will be just changing the configuration file...

any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: read : fgets, copy : strncpy and strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use any well known data representaion format like json or xml for your input? by using this kinds of formats you will have no problems with future changes

json will be a good choice and there are implememtaions for c (libjansson etc.)

***EDIT***

ok, then store your configuration data in file, use some format (i prefer json...) 
you will need offset and len infomration:

```
    [
      {
        offset: 0, 
        len: 10
      }
      {
       offset: 10, 
       len: 10
      }
    ]
```

then you can read this file in your programm and use the information to parse your input:

```
    int offset = getOffset(0);
    int len;  = getLen(0);
    int i;
    for(i = offset; i<len; i++)
    {
      doSomething(input[i]);
    }
```

Comment: There are native or legacy data flows still in ACTIVE which they cant be converted into XML format. Hence I'm looking for some suggestion to convert the Fixed length input format files to output files in Fixed length format in this case.